# How do I stop EF from generating useless code, does it matter?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, entity-framework

I am running a linq query like

```
dbEntity.Where(x => x.FundType== "E")
        .Where(x => x.ReportDate == new DateTime(2014,10,23))
        .GroupBy(x => x.ReportDate)
        .Select(groupedDate => new CategorySourceData
            {
                ReportDate = groupedDate.Key,
                TotalFlow = groupedDate.Sum(x => x.Flow)
            }
        .ToList();
```

I want it to give me the same results as this query and with a similar runtime

```
select ReportDate,
       sum(flow)
from vwDailyFundFlowDetail
where FundType = 'E'
group by ReportDate
```

Ef generates a query that returns the correct data. However, my hanwritten query takes about 13s on my test set and the ef generated query takes 24s on the same test set.

The ef query looks like

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ReportDate], 
     CAST( [GroupBy1].[A1] AS real) AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ReportDate] AS [K1], 
        SUM([Extent1].[Flow]) AS [A1]
        FROM (SELECT 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[HFundId] AS [HFundId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ReportDate] AS [ReportDate], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Flow] AS [Flow], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ForexChange] AS [ForexChange], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[AssetsEnd] AS [AssetsEnd], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ShareID] AS [ShareID], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ShareClass] AS [ShareClass], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ISIN] AS [ISIN], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[CUSIP] AS [CUSIP], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Ticker] AS [Ticker], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[AssetsStart] AS [AssetsStart], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[PortfolioChange] AS [PortfolioChange], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundName] AS [FundName], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[SSID] AS [SSID], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Advisor] AS [Advisor], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[GEOID] AS [GEOID], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FTCID] AS [FTCID], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[BenchIndex] AS [BenchIndex], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundType] AS [FundType], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ETF] AS [ETF], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Domicile] AS [Domicile], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[GeographicFocus] AS [GeographicFocus], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Currency] AS [Currency], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundDomicile] AS [FundDomicile], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Manager] AS [Manager], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundCurrency] AS [FundCurrency], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Benchmark] AS [Benchmark], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundFocus] AS [FundFocus], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[NetChange] AS [NetChange], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundId] AS [FundId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[InstOrRetail] AS [InstOrRetail], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Hedge_yn] AS [Hedge_yn], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[SRI_yn] AS [SRI_yn], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[SCID] AS [SCID], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[DistributorId] AS [DistributorId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Distributor] AS [Distributor], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Frontier] AS [Frontier], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundCategory] AS [FundCategory], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Commodity] AS [Commodity], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[CurrId] AS [CurrId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Idx] AS [Idx], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Bear] AS [Bear], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Dividend] AS [Dividend], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[AbsoluteReturn] AS [AbsoluteReturn], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Islamic_yn] AS [Islamic_yn], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Ins] AS [Ins], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Inf] AS [Inf], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Silver] AS [Silver], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Gold] AS [Gold], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[AG] AS [AG], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Metal] AS [Metal], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Administrator] AS [Administrator], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Custodian] AS [Custodian], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Bear2x] AS [Bear2x], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Bear3x] AS [Bear3x], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Leverage1x] AS [Leverage1x], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Leverage2x] AS [Leverage2x], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[MuniStateId] AS [MuniStateId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Leverage3x] AS [Leverage3x], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Synthetic_ETF] AS [Synthetic_ETF], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Physical_ETF] AS [Physical_ETF], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[IG] AS [IG], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[EMC] AS [EMC], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[EMS] AS [EMS], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[EMM] AS [EMM], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[MuniState] AS [MuniState], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundQualityId] AS [FundQualityId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[FundDurationId] AS [FundDurationId], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[QualityName] AS [QualityName], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[DurationName] AS [DurationName], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ClosedEnd] AS [ClosedEnd], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[MLP] AS [MLP], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ArrivalTime] AS [ArrivalTime], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ArrivalDayCode] AS [ArrivalDayCode], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[DActivationDate] AS [DActivationDate], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[WActivationDate] AS [WActivationDate], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[MActivationDate] AS [MActivationDate], 
      [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ShareClassCurrency] AS [ShareClassCurrency]
      FROM [dbo].[vwDailyFundFlowDetail] AS [vwDailyFundFlowDetail]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[FundType] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[FundType] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND (0 = (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            WHERE 1 = 0
        )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END))
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[ReportDate]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0=N'E',@p__linq__1='E'
```

The part of the where clause where it goes

```
AND (0 = (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            WHERE 1 = 0
        )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END))
```

seems to be the main issue. As far as I can tell that case statement is always 0 so this is always true. The presence of this part of the query is changing a single part of the execution plan from [image]

to look like
[image]

If I remove the case statement from my where clause then the execution plan and run time of this query and my handwritten sql become identical as far as I can tell. How do I stop EF from adding this part of the where clause? What did I do in my linq code that made EF add this to the query?

Comment: show end of query (Single, First, ToList...)

Comment: Try combining your where clause: .Where(x => x.FundType == "E" && x.ReportDate == new DateTime(2014,10,23)).

Comment: I did that and the where clause stayed the same in the generated query

Comment: your SQL query is not equivalent to your linq query, the linq query has this `.Where(x => x.ReportDate == new DateTime(2014,10,23))` but it is not present in your SQL query. Also the linq query seems to return only 1 group (because there is just one ReportDate filtered out before). That kind of grouping is abnormal. So you can try removing the `.Where(x => x.ReportDate == new DateTime(2014,10,23))` part and see if the generated SQL query is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set  `Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;` on your `DBContext`

This will prevent the added `is null` checks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: this can break other logic

Comment: @Backs - You don't need to change it for every query (ie in the constuctor). I am suggesting you make the change for the scope of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

I guess, you use Datebase first and EDMX file. So, check your mapping is not a `DefiningQuery`.
Open EDMX and find strings like:

```
<EntitySet Name="vwDailyFundFlowDetail" EntityType="yourbase.Store.vwDailyFundFlowDetail" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="vwDailyFundFlowDetail">
<DefiningQuery>SELECT 
  [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[HFundId] AS [HFundId], 
  [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ReportDate] AS [ReportDate], 
  [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[Flow] AS [Flow], 
  [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ForexChange] AS [ForexChange], 
  [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[AssetsEnd] AS [AssetsEnd], 
  [vwDailyFundFlowDetail].[ShareID] AS [ShareID], 
  //...others
  FROM [dbo].[vwDailyFundFlowDetail] AS [vwDailyFundFlowDetail]</DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

And replace it with smth like this:

```
<EntitySet Name="vwDailyFundFlowDetail" EntityType="yourbase.Store.vwDailyFundFlowDetail" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
```

Check, if FundType is must be nullable. If not - mark it `explicitly` as not nullable:
[image: set property to not nullable]

I think, it will help and later we can research new generated query.

Comment: FundType doesnt have to be nullable but its a string, Is there some attribute or something to mark strings as not nullable with EF6? Also vwDailyFundFlowDetail did have a defining query, I removed it and set string like you said. The query no longer is explicitly calling all the columns, but the query being generated is now going `FROM [EPFRUI_ModelStoreContainer].[vwDailyFundFlowDetail]` instead of `FROM [dbo].[vwDailyFundFlowDetail]`. I tried this with store:Type="Views" as well as its a view, but the same results. The string is using the same yourbase.Store as all my other tables

Comment: @AlexanderBurke be careful, shema attribute must be `Schema="dbo"` not `store:Schema="dbo"`

Comment: @AlexanderBurke added pic, how to set property to not null